# How do I make Apple Script open Script Editor and write a new script?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have tried to do

```
tell application "Script Editor"
    make new script with properties {name:"this is a test", body:"and 
    more text"}
end tell
```

but it came up with the error

'error "Script Editor got an error: Can’t make class file." number -2710 from file to class"

Comment: Does Script Editor support a class named `script`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
tell application "Script Editor"
    make new document with properties {name:"this is a test", contents:"and 
more text"}
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the "Script Editor to a different application

```
tell application "Script Editor"
    make new script with properties {name:"this is a test", body:"and 
    more text"}
end tell
```